# RewriteRule: unknown flag 'QSD'

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I copied the working code on xampp and then pasted it on the live .htacces file and now I get 500 server error.

The error log reads `RewriteRule: unknown flag 'QSD'`

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/?inbox/([\d.a-zA-Z]*)$ /inbox?pg=$1 [QSD,L]
RewriteRule ^/?sent/([\d.a-zA-Z]*)$ /sent?pg=$1 [QSD,L]
RewriteRule ^/?deleted/([\d.a-zA-Z]*)$ /deleted?pg=$1 [QSD,L]
RewriteRule ^/?view/([\d.a-zA-Z]*)$ /view?content=$1 [QSD,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: It is due to older version of Apache on live server. But why do you need `QSD`?

Comment: @anubhava I got it online tutorial, I am trying to hide `pg` and `content` from a url

Comment: [The documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsd) says the `QSD` flag is available in apache 2.4.0 and higher. What version are you running?

Comment: @Magna: Just replace `QSD` by `QSA`

Comment: @anubhava I don't think `QSA` will discard the query strings nor its alternative of it?

Comment: @anubhava Replacing `QSD` with `QSA` is absolutely the wrong thing to do here (it does the complete opposite and _appends_ the query string from the request, whereas `QSD` discards it). Just remove the `QSD` flag - it's not required here, since the query string will be discarded anyway.

Comment: I very well know what `QSD` is how it is different from `QSA`. However OP' was using `QSD`  **by mistake** only and looking at OP's comment it is clear it worked for him.

Comment: @anubhava Sorry, yes you are right - just realised that the OP may have entered this in error and intended to write `QSA` after all. (Although the fact that they supposedly got this from another tutorial also threw me).